# Custom ImageView with colorFilter keeps same filter if same drawable is used again

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom imageview that should have the possibility to set the colour of an icon either programmatically or from the layouts. 
This works.

Lets say I use a white icon on a black background.

Then, if the same icon drawable in another place of the app and invert the colours, black icon on white back ground. Then only the icons that has been used before stays in its original colour. And I can't change it either from the layout or programmatically. Same activity but different fragments.

This is the class.

```
public class IconView extends ImageView {

    public IconView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public IconView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.iconViewStyle);
    }

    public IconView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        TypedArray attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.IconView, defStyle, 0);
        int color = attributes.getColor(R.styleable.IconView_icon_color, Color.WHITE);
        ColorFilter cf = new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        if (getDrawable() != null) getDrawable().setColorFilter(cf);
        attributes.recycle();
    }

    public void setIconColor(int color) {
        getDrawable().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or might android reuse drawables somehow that once they are drawn they stay that way (seems weird)!

Comment: I got the same behaviour too although i use the same drawable within MenuItem and ImageView, i think this has to do with android cache

Comment: Exactly! Check the accepted answer for help!

Comment: The problem is because i use MenuItem, and on MenuItem we doesn't have .setColorFilter(), instead we use MenuItem.getIcon().setColorFilter()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the Drawable is being cached, hence the filter is being re-used.
Instead of `getDrawable.setColorFilter`, try `this.setColorFilter`, which should set the filter on a copy of the drawable, that is not shared with other instances.

Answer (score 5):

I know that another answer has been selected as the correct one, but it sounds to me like you are having a different issue to what the answer implies. If you are using the same image (especially if it's from a resource) within the same activity, then all of them will be modified when you apply a colour filter. This is because drawables from res are immutable, and will share the same state. To avoid this, use `getDrawable().mutate().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)`.

The docs for `mutate()` contain more information on this.

Comment: I have tested it and it is working as my case is different with @just_user and i can't use the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.  Just to add some more detail to Marcus Hoopers answer (which I upvoted).

I had my drawables referenced in array.xml

```
<integer-array name="tab_icons_transparent">
    <item>@drawable/ic_action_home</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_pushup_t</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_action_achievement</item>
</integer-array>
```

My initial code was like this:

```
View iconView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.some_layout, null);
TypedArray tabIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.tab_icons_transparent);
iconView.findViewById(R.id.tab_icon).setBackgroundResource(tabIcons.getResourceId(i, -1));
```

And changing the third line as follows fixed it for me (after many hours wasted trying to change xml and source files):

```
Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, tabIcons.getResourceId(i, -1)).mutate();
iconView.findViewById(R.id.tab_icon).setBackground(drawable);
```